# Using generic method parameters in Java

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to use generic methods in java for the first time.  It isn't working, and it appears to me that Java generics are simply not meant to be used this way - that I will need to implement a common interface rather then using a generic method.  Please confirm (or deny) that conclusion.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
public <T> void updateItem( T item ) {
  String itemKey = item.getKey();
  ...
```

This gives me the error 'The method getKey() is undefined for the type T'.

Looking into why this doesn't work I see that type erasure "replaces all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded".

The only way I can 'bound' my type T is if I create a common subclass or interface for all the types I was planning to use, and if I do that then I can use polymorphism rather then generics.

Comment: What is T supposed to be? You could use `<T extends SomeClassWithGetKey>`

Comment: Looks like you want to use an interface, not generics.

Comment: I have this idea (from Python or C++) that I don't have to specify what T is.  T will be type checked when it is invoked with a type.

Comment: This won't work in Java.

Comment: @Tom generics are a compile time feature in Java.  It is type checked at compile time, not when it is invoked, hence it has to be resolvable at compile time.

Comment: @Affe Okay, but C++ is also compile time - I think the difference is that C++ doesn't check the function until it is actually used (and creates a new implementation for each invocation, depending on the compiler).

Comment: The *only* thing Templates and Generics have in common is the use of `<>` in their syntax :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is right. Method `getKey()` is not defined in class `T`. However if you define your method as following:

```
public <T extends Entry> void updateItem( T item ) {
  String itemKey = item.getKey();
```

the compiler can find `getKey()` method. Please pay attention that I used `<T extends Entry>` (I mean `java.util.Map.Entry`). This class has method `getKey()` and compiler can resolve it.

Comment: Yeah, I had this idea (from Python and C++) that the compiler wouldn't try to resolve the call until invocation (or runtime in Python) so as long as it worked as used it was fine.

Comment: The odd thing (to me) is that, if T has a common base class (Entry above) then I don't need generics at all.

Comment: @Tom That's corrent - just have the method take `Entry` for example. Sometimes polymorphism is enough and you don't need generics.